# JavaScript: Why []+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{}); returns "42"

Tags: javascript

Saw this in my newsletter. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.  I still can't figured it out.

```
[]+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{});    //=>  "42"
```

Comment: never seen something like that, i will be interrested to know what that is.

Comment: Because Javascript has ridiculous numeric coercion rules. (And, it's essentially impossible to search for previous instances where this question has been asked.)

Comment: If you wonder why JS does certain things the way it does, I encourage you do read the spec. You just have to look at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7 and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1

Comment: Because `[]+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{}) === []+(-~true-~true)+(-~true)`, obviously.

Comment: At any rate, the answer is the same as the answer to the question of life the universe and everything... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29 )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluating:

```
~{}
```

is evaluated using the internal function:

```
~ToInt32({})
```

which gives -1.

Ref ECMA spec - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5
and this explanation - http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcToInt32

Therefore, in this case

```
(-~{}-~{}) == 2
(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{}) == 4
```

As you have `[]+` in the start of expression, javascript use plus operands like string. So you have `"" + "4" + "2" = "42"`

Comment: You were about 20 seconds faster than me. :)

Comment: `~` is the Bitwise NOT operator. It converts `0` to `-1`

Comment: `{} != undefined` (Feel free to test this).

Comment: `~{}` is the same as `~ToInt32({})`, which converts `{}` to `0`. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5 . Answers to questions like this without citing the spec are dubious.

Comment: Is it because undefined is interpreted as false. So, ~undefined = ~false = -1

Comment: hmm yes, Amit is correct, stating `{}==undefined` is not helpful, and Felix then explains it nicely. Someone should write a better answer or meanwhile in true SO spirit I will collectively take the suggestions and go for an edit.

Answer (score 3):

The `~` operator is a Bitwise NOT operator. It returns the "1's complement" of a number. Because of that `{}` is converted into a number, resulting in `NaN`. The same would happen with `+{} == NaN`. The bitwise not of `~NaN == -1`. So:
`(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{}) == 4` & `(-~{}-~{}) == 2`

The DefaultValue for an empty array is an empty string. For example `[]==[]+[] && []+[]==''`

From that, the full parsing is:
`[]+ /*converted to ''+*/ (-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{}) /*Equals numeric 4, but concatenated as a string to become '4'*/ + (-~{}-~{}) /*Equals numeric 2, but concatenated as a string to become '2'*/` and the end result is actually `'42'`.

You can validate this via `typeof([]+(-~{}-~{}-~{}-~{})+(-~{}-~{})) === 'string'`