# Does anyone know what this in Javascript means? `ǀǀ+(ǀ==ǀ-->ǀ+ǀ<--ǀ==ǀ)+ǀǀ`

Tags: javascript

So I was looking at someones code on a website and while looking around, I saw this:

```js
var ǀ = 1;
var ǀǀ = 21;
var s = ǀǀ+(ǀ==ǀ-->ǀ+ǀ<--ǀ==ǀ)+ǀǀ;
document.writeln(s);
```

This somehow equates to 42? Does anyone know how they are doing this? I thought || and | where for `or`?

Comment: It's lots of operators, not one. Kind of like how `1*1+1-1/1` isn't an operator.

Comment: Hmm, your deleted [Obama one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41838123/73226) was the [chuck Norris](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color) question recycled. You've just asked a [JavaScript question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838887/what-is-the-javascript-operator)  that was a recycled version of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/73226 where's this one from?

Comment: Just walk through the var s-line. There are two variables | and ||. 
It is 21+( 1==1 - - > 1+1 < - - 1==1) + 21;  
Minus Minus 1 (--1) is +1, so it is just comparing if 1==1 +1 > 1 ; 1==1 is true 1, 1+1 is not larger 1 and so on.. So that whole part between the two brackets equals 0 and it's just 21+21.

Comment: It evaluates to `21+(1==0>1+1<0==1)+21`. Which means: `21+(false>2<false)+21`. Then, `false>2` is false (because 0<2) and then `false<false` is false ( because 0 == 0, not 0<0). Since the stuff in parentheses all evaluates to false (0), 21+0+21 is 42.

Comment: It's new operator introduced in ES 10 :)

Comment: I't obviously not going to be a +84568 votes question

Comment: @MartinSmith - seems to be a '42' thing (life, the universe, etc) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555155/why-is-the-answer-42 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790761/javascript-why-returns-42

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ǀ` and `ǀǀ` are (Unicode) variable names.

Space it out:

```
var ǀ = 1;
var ǀǀ = 21;
var s = ǀǀ + (ǀ == ǀ-- > ǀ + ǀ < --ǀ == ǀ) + ǀǀ;
```

Apply operator precedence and associativity:

```
var ǀ = 1;
var ǀǀ = 21;
var s = (ǀǀ + ((ǀ == ((ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ)) < --ǀ)) == ǀ)) + ǀǀ;
```

Apply order of evaluation:

```
var a = ǀǀ + ((ǀ == ((ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ)) < --ǀ)) == ǀ);
var s = a + ǀǀ;
```

```
var b = (ǀ == ((ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ)) < --ǀ)) == ǀ;
var a = ǀǀ + b;
```

```
var c = ǀ == ((ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ)) < --ǀ);
var b = c == ǀ;
```

```
var d = (ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ)) < --ǀ;
var c = ǀ == d;
```

```
var e = ǀ-- > (ǀ + ǀ);
var d = e < --ǀ;
```

```
var g = ǀ--;
var f = ǀ + ǀ;
var e = g > f;
```

Evaluate:

```
var ǀ = 1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var g = ǀ--;
var f = ǀ + ǀ;
var e = g > f;
var d = e < --ǀ;
var c = ǀ == d;
var b = c == ǀ;
var a = ǀǀ + b;
var s = a + ǀǀ;
```

```
var ǀ = 0;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var g = 1;
var f = ǀ + ǀ;
```

```
var ǀ = 0;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var f = 0 + 0;
var e = g > f;
```

```
var ǀ = 0;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var e = 1 > 0;  // true
var d = e < --ǀ;
```

```
var ǀ = -1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var d = true < -1;  // false
var c = ǀ == d;
```

```
var ǀ = -1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var c = -1 == -1;  // true
var b = c == ǀ;
```

```
var ǀ = -1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var b = true == -1;  // false
var a = ǀǀ + b;
```

```
var ǀ = -1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var a = 21 + false;  // 21
var s = a + ǀǀ;
```

```
var ǀ = -1;
var ǀǀ = 21;

var s = 21 + 21;  // 42
```

Answer (score 4):

They're (ab)using a character that looks a whole lot like a vertical bar (`|`) such as what's used in "or" (`||`).

You could rewrite their code like this:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 21;
var s = b + (a == a-- > a + a < --a == a) + b;
document.writeln(s);
```

or further simplified:

```js
var s = 21 + (1 == 1 > 0 + 0 < -1 == -1) + 21;
document.writeln(s);

// Even further simplified
var s = 21 + (true > false < true) + 21;
document.writeln(s);

// Clean up that middle case
var s = 21 + (false) + 21;
document.writeln(s);

// Coerce to a number
var s = 21 + 0 + 21;
document.writeln(s);

// Last simplification
var s = 21 + 21;
document.writeln(s);
```

No special operators. Just normal ones smushed together with odd-looking variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It is a joke (a bad one). It isn't an operator. It is a collection of variable and operators put together to look intentionally confusing.

It is taking advantage of the visual similarities between `ǀ` (U+01C0 : LATIN LETTER DENTAL CLICK {pipe}) which is a character you can use in a variable name and `|` (U+007C : VERTICAL LINE {vertical bar}) which is an operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mixture of obfuscation, and some abuse of weak typing.

First, `ǀ` and `ǀǀ` here are just variables with funny names - names that look a bit like, but aren't actually, the common character `|`, which *would* be an operator. So let's swap them out:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 21;
var s = b+(a==a-->a+a<--a==a)+b;
document.writeln(s);
```

Now we have various operations on one line, we need to work out [the precedence of the different operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so we can break it down in the right order. The operators we have, in order of highest to lowest precedence, are:

- `(`...`)` to give a section higher precedence
- postfix `--`
- prefix `--`
- `+`
- `>` and `<` (left to right)
- `==` (multiple times, left to right)

So we can calculate the sum in this order:

- the part inside the brackets is the only interesting part, the rest is `21 + (something) + 21`
- `a--` gives `1`, but changes `a` to 0 (`b+(a==1>a+a<--a==a)+b`)
- `--a` changes `a` to `-1` and gives `-1` (`b+(a==1>a+a<-1==a)+b`)
- `a` is now `-1`, so the very middle becomes `-1+-1` (`b+(a==1>-1+-1<-1==a)+b`) which is `-2` (`b+(a==1>-2<-1==a)+b`)
- `1>-2` is `true` (`b+(a==true<-1==a)+b`)
- `true<-1` is `false` because `true` is treated as `1` (`b+(a==false==a)+b`)
- `a` is `-1`, but `false` is `0`, so `a==false` is like saying `-1==0`, which is `false` (`b+(false==a)+b`)
- `false==a` is again `false` (`b+(false)+b`)
- treated as a number, `false` is 0, so `b + 0 + b` is `21 + 0 + 21` is `42`

Interestingly, the in-place modification of `a` makes this open to various interpretations. For instance, it might be that all the unmodified `a`s are substituted as `1` (i.e. before the `a++`), giving some variations:

- with `a` as `1`, the very middle is `1+1` (`b+(a==1>1+1<-1==a)+b`) which is `0` (`b+(a==1>2<-1==a)+b`)
- `1>2` is `false` (`b+(a==false<-1==a)+b`)
- however, `false<-1` is still `false`, so we get back to our original sequence